# Qualifier in EntityStore

Tags: entity

I am trying to construct some entities by myself. However, I found the examples given by the documents quite confusing. Can someone explain how to use the qualifiers? The example in the documentation uses date as a qualifier:

```
EntityRegister[EntityStore["beehive" -> <|

 "Entities" -> <|

   "lisa" -> <|
     {"Population", "Date" -> All} -> 
      TimeSeries[{
        {{2013}, 100000},
        {{2014}, 200000},
        {{2015}, 150000}
        }]
     |>,
   "tom" -> <|
     {"Population", "Date" -> All} -> 
      TimeSeries[{
        {{2013}, 300000},
        {{2014}, 200000},
        {{2015}, 200000}
        }]
     |>
   |>,

 "Properties" -> <|

   "Population" -> <|

     "DefaultFunction" -> 
      Function[ent, ent[Dated["Population", All]]["LastValue"]]
     |>,
   {"Population", "Date" -> _?DateObjectQ} -> <|

     "DefaultFunction" -> Function[{ent, quals},
       Round[ent[Dated["Population", All]][quals["Date"]]]
       ]
     |>
   |>
 |>]];
```

I have a hard time understanding the following qualifiers

```
    {"Population", "Date" -> All} -> TimeSeries[{
   {{2013}, 100000},
   {{2014}, 200000},
   {{2015}, 150000}
   }]
```

Can someone explain how to understand this construct? How to use qualifiers other than date?